# 403 error in latest blog

Tags: bug, blog, podcast

In the latest blog post I cannot see what is written, I think that's the podcast?

Now all the podcasts , in this [page](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/) are giving the same error. But it used to work before. Is it possible to use other distribution other than Amazon CloudFront?

[image]

Comment: I guess asking you to move to a supported country is out of order? ;)

Comment: At the top of the page alternative sources are listed, like [overcast](https://overcast.fm/itunes1483510527/the-stack-overflow-podcast) or [soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange) do those work for you? I'm not sure if the license allows for that but I've also rehosted the last pod cast on glitch.com: https://foamy-drip.glitch.me/

Comment: Thank you @rene I used the glitch link to watch the podcast of last week, and the [overcast](https://overcast.fm/itunes1483510527/the-stack-overflow-podcast) link to watch this week's podcast!